# Upper bound for the largest number of consecutive integers such that each is divisible by primes less than the nth prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Let a(n) be the largest number of consecutive integers such

that each is divisible by a prime <= the n-th prime.

On oeis.org : https://oeis.org/A058989

there is an upper bound mentioned which is

$ a(n) < $${n^2} \cdot {(ln(n))^2}$

This upper bound is approximately equal to $ {P_n}^2$

since $${P_n} > n \cdot \ln \left( n \right)
$$

I wonder if this can be done better. My hope is that an upper bound can be found

where $ a(n) < \frac{{{n^2} \cdot {{(ln(n))}^2}}}{2}$

for some sufficiently large value of n.

A thought came to my mind.

Let a2(n) be the largest number of consecutive integers such

that each is divisible by an **odd** prime <= the n-th prime.

What would be the upper bound for this ?

If an upper bound for this can be shown to be less than

$ $${a_2}(n) < \frac{{{n^2} \cdot {{(ln(n))}^2}}}{4} $

then we would also have that

$ a(n) < \frac{{{n^2} \cdot {{(ln(n))}^2}}}{2}$

Comment: where on On oeis.org  ?

Comment: Upto which $n$ does your tighter bound hold ?

Comment: I believe that my tighter bound holds all known values of n.

Comment: This is known as Jacobsthal's function, if you want to look up more about it. Basically, we know much less about the size of this function than we would like to.